# Take multiple post values and put them together

Tags: php

I have multiple post values for a full name:

```
$_POST['title'] $_POST['first_name'] $_POST['last_name'] $_POST['suffix'];
```

I am trying to make them put out something like this:

```
$name = Mr. John Doe Jr.
```

I have tried:

```
$name = $_POST['title'] + $_POST['first_name'] + $_POST['last_name'] + $_POST['suffix'];
```

because of my history of `javascript` but this did not work. It resulted in `0` as the value for `$name`

So how do I get these together into one string using `PHP`

Comment: That's very basic knowledge. Next time try to search before asking (eg. `php join variables` will give you some useful links).

Comment: @ElonThan -- I searched for 2 hours trying to find a solution. It's hard to google something when you don't know what it's called :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP uses a full stop as a concat operator.

```
$name = $_POST['title'] . $_POST['first_name'] // etc
```

When you are using a `+` sign, PHP will actually try to evaluate the string into a number and then try to give you a numeric result - hence the output of zero.

To also add the punctuation you wanted (assuming they aren't already in the POSTs) you can do this:

```
$name = $_POST['title'] .". ". $_POST['first_name'] // etc
                     //  ^^ which will insert a full stop after the title.
```

Comment: Ok this worked. How do I place spaces between them. Right now I'm getting `Mr.JohnDoeJr.` instead of `Mr. John Doe Jr.`

Comment: @user2948950 I just added an edit that shows how you can insert manually written strings (punctuation actually) in the answer. You can obviously insert spaces inside the string as well.